# Project files are not appearing after adding cocoapods - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have been working on an xcode project for iPad/iPhone and need to add firebase. So I went through the usual steps of generating the .xcworkspace using my terminal and the necessary podfile to include firebase dependencies.

The pod "stuff" seems to be there fine but the project is red. So there is nothing to build.

Attached is a screenshot.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: I created all the pod "stuff" on my desktop and then dragged all those files into the folder containing my original xcode project... Why would you do that ? You can simply integrate pods to your existing project.

Comment: Check under pods if firebase is installed

Comment: Actually i have replicate this project from existing project which have the cocoapds. but when i close it and open the project it doesn't show project files. Yes it has installed firebase pods.

Comment: you should simply integrate pods/libs in existing project through command line and not move files between projects to integrate libs

Comment: How can i fix this.. i want all the files back.

Comment: Try regenerating your workspace: In your project folder, run `pod deintegrate`, delete the .xcworkspace file and run `pod install` again.